# Confusion about the usage of angle brackets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning flutter right now and I am reading some tutorial code. I know angle brackets e.g.  refer to a set of widgets but how I should understand follow code then:

```
    return Center(
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider<CartModel>(
        data: CartModel(),
        child: Builder(builder: (context) {...}
```

This is a set of CartModel? but then what does the ChangeNotifierProvider mean here?

Answer (score 1):

The `ChangeNotifierProvider` is there to listen to the notifications of the `CartModel` Provider.

The `CartModel` is the type of provider that the `ChangeNotifierProvider` will listen to for updates.

Comment: If this answer helped please mark it as accepted. It'll help others concentrate on solving other people's issue instead of answering the question that is already answered. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

`ChangeNotifierProvider` is the constructor with the argument.

```
data: CartModel(),
child: Builder(builder: (context) {...}
```

which will call the build method of class `ChangeNotifierProvider`.